# Visual Studio Code split terminal on startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to have visual studio code launch the split terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>) on startup?

Or alternatively, is it possible to save my screen layout so I don't have to split the terminal manually?

Comment: Do you mean *Split editor*?

Comment: No, terminal splitting / multiple terminals https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-splitting

Comment: Funny, on [Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) that keybinding is mapped to the split editor command xD

Comment: Never mind... It also splits the terminal if you focus it. I need some sleep!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of this functionality was added since the question was asked.  Now you can put this into your tasks.json:

```
 {
  "label": "SplitTerminalonStartip",
  "command": "${command:workbench.action.terminal.split}",
  "type": "shell",
  "problemMatcher": [],
  "runOptions": { "runOn": "folderOpen" }
},
```

and the terminal will be split on startup.

Comment: I presume `"type": "shell"` means that both terminals will open a shell. What if I wanted to different terminals. (In my case that would be an R terminal and my default shell, in that order from left to right.)

Answer (score 0):

1- inside `.vscode` folder `tasks.json` add two tasks
one to create a new terminal and another to split that terminal

2-run the `SplitTerminalonStartup` task once by clicking `ctrl` +`shift` +`p` and write "run task" and press enter then choose `SplitTerminalonStartup` after clicking that a pop up message appears asking to allow this task to run automatically every time you open up vscode

```
"tasks": [

    {
        "label": "CreateTerminalonStartup",
        "command": "${command:workbench.action.terminal.new}",
        "type": "shell",
        "problemMatcher": [],
    },
    {
        "label": "SplitTerminalonStartup",
        "dependsOn": [
            "CreateTerminalonStartup"
        ],
        "command": "${command:workbench.action.terminal.split}",
        "type": "shell",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "runOptions": {
            "runOn": "folderOpen"
        }
    }
]
```